# Why don't standard libraries implement std::atomic for structs under 8 bytes in a lock-free manner?

Tags: c++, c++17, atomic, lock-free, stdatomic

Assuming that the architecture can support 8 byte scalars in a lock free manner for std::atomic.  Why don't standard libraries provide similar specializations for structs that are under 8 bytes?

A simple implementation of such an std::atomic specialization can just serialize/deserialize (with `std::memcpy`) the struct into the equivalent `std::uintx_t` where `x` is the width of the struct in bits (rounded off to the closest power of 2 that is larger than or equal to the width of the struct).  This would be well defined because these structs are required by std::atomic to be trivially copyable.

Eg. https://godbolt.org/z/sxSeId, here `Something` is only 3 bytes, but the implementation calls `__atomic_load` and `__atomic_exchange`, both of which use a lock table.

Comment: gcc gets it right if you make the struct 4 bytes (but not 3), see https://godbolt.org/z/d1OCmG.  clang doesn't.

Comment: @PaulSanders Interesting, I wonder why 3 bytes doesn't work..

Comment: There is no x86 instruction that loads/stores 3 bytes, let alone atomically.

Comment: @rustyx Ah, sorry, but you could always take up more than the size up to the next power of 2 though right?  Section `§[atomics.types.generic]p3` allows this - *The representation of an atomic specialization need not have the same size as its corresponding argument type.* I guess there are portability problems with that though?

Comment: @rustyx On most compilers the struct is padded up to 4 bytes. As in `sizeof(S)` is never 3.

Comment: But it could be 3 bytes, and then suddenly you require atomic access to 3 bytes, and you're in trouble.

Comment: @Curious: If you force the alignment of the struct to be 4, then it works fine even in GCC.

Comment: @NicolBolas, it seems like clang doesn't https://godbolt.org/z/N6P6Hs. Any reason for this or is it just something that needs to be fixed?

Comment: @Curious: When I said "force the alignment", I meant with `alignas(4)`.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ah interesting, any idea why a single byte alignment doesn't work?  I didn't realize setting a higher alignment would make it use atomic instructions all of a sudden..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linux's `atomic<T>` unfortunately(?) doesn't alignas / pad up to a power-of-2 size.  `std::atomic<Something> arr[10]` has sizeof(arr) = 30.  (https://godbolt.org/z/WzK66xebr)

---

Use `struct Something { alignas(4) char a; char b,c; };`
(Not `alignas(4) char a,b,c;` because that would make *each* char padded to 4 bytes so they could each be aligned.)

**Objects with a non-power-of-2 size might span a cache-line boundary** so using a wider 4-byte load is not always possible.

Plus pure stores would always have to use a CAS (e.g. `lock cmpxchg`) to avoid inventing writes to a byte outside the object: obviously you can't use two separate `mov` stores (2-byte + 1-byte) because that wouldn't be atomic, unless you do that inside a TSX transaction with a retry loop.

---

x86 load/store are only guaranteed atomic for memory accesses that don't cross an 8-byte boundary.  (On some vendors / uarches, a cache line boundary.  Or for possibly-uncacheable loads/stores, basically natural alignment is what you need).  [Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624881/why-is-integer-assignment-on-a-naturally-aligned-variable-atomic-on-x86)

Your  `struct Something { char a, b, c; };` has no alignment requirement so there's no C++ rule that prevents a `Something` object from spanning 2 cache lines.  That would make a plain-`mov` load/store of it definitely non-atomic.

gcc and clang choose to implement **`atomic<T>` with the same layout / object-representation as `T`** (regardless of being lock-free or not).  Therefore `atomic<Something>` is a 3-byte object.  An array of `atomic<Something>` thus necessarily has some of those objects spanning cache line boundaries, and can't have padding outside the object because that's not how arrays work in C.  `sizeof()` = 3 tells you the array layout.  **This makes lock-free `atomic<Something>` impossible.**  (Unless you load/store with `lock cmpxchg` to be atomic even on cache-line splits, which would produce a huge performance penalty in the cases where that did happen.  Better to make developers fix their struct.)

The `atomic<T>` class can have a higher alignment requirement than `T`, for example `atomic<int64_t>` has alignof(atomic_int64_t) == 8, unlike `alignof(int64_t) == 4` on many 32-bit platforms (including the i386 System V ABI).

If gcc/clang hadn't made the choice to keep the layout the same, they could have had `atomic<T>` pad small objects up to the next power of 2 and add alignment so they could be lock-free.  That would be a valid implementation choice.  I can't think of any downsides.

---

Fun fact, gcc's C11 `_Atomic` support is [slightly broken on 32-bit platforms with 64-bit lockless atomics](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65146#c4) : `_Atomic int64_t` can be misaligned inside structs leading to tearing.  They still haven't updated the ABI for `_Atomic` types to have natural alignment.

But g++'s C++11 std::atomic uses a template class in a header that fixed that bug a while ago (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65147); ensuring that `atomic<T>` has natural alignment (up to some power of 2 size) even if `T` has alignment < size.  Thus there's no way they can span any boundary wider than they are.

Comment: Oh the cacheline splits actually make a ton of sense, thanks!